# How to fetch the Feature details, ID directly from Content Database

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, feature, content-database

Is it possible to a get the details of a specific feature thats available in content database?

my custom feature name is JobReminders_TimerJob_Timer_JobRemindersFeature
using SSMS , i wanna find this record from the content db and wanna delete the same.

Which Table is responsible for storing the custom Feature in content db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly querying the database is highly discouraged. Adding, updating, or deleting entries from the database is outright unsupported. As the feature will be referenced in multiple places, you should instead go through the SharePoint APIs to do this activity.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a  little bit , " you should instead go through the SharePoint APIs " , should i go through SSOM+C# ? or through powershell ? am little bit confused about that sentence.

Comment: Correct, using SSOM or PowerShell (which leverages SSOM). You can probably get the code you need from https://github.com/achimismaili/featureadmin.

Comment: Yes i have gone through multiple threads in this forums regarding the activation, deletion of feature at farm level etc and  was able to  remove those features - faulty- using featureadmin and removed from content db

Answer (score 0):

Agree with user6024 info: "**Directly querying the database is highly discouraged. Adding, updating, or deleting entries from the database is outright unsupported**"

Using content db join "Features" and "FeatureTracking" tables and get the Feature information.

```
USE [ContentDBName]

SELECT DISTINCT FEATURE.FeatureId,FTRACKING.FeatureTitle,FTRACKING.FeatureDescription
FROM Features FEATURE 
JOIN FeatureTracking FTRACKING 
  ON FEATURE.FeatureId = FTRACKING.FeatureId WHERE FTRACKING.FeatureId = 'EA23650B-0340-4708-B465-441A41C37AF7'
```